# RAILS YML file uninitialized constant issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, yaml

In rails is it possible to get a class variable in YML file. I am having plan.yml and in that

```
small:
 count: <%=Unlimited.max_value%>
```

calling a class method this method is in config folder.But i am getting  uninitialized constant Unlimited (NameError).

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: plan.yml is in config folder and loaded using load_configs.rb which is in same config folder and the Unlimited class in defined in config/initializer

Answer (score 1):

The problem will be to do with where you're calling the `yml` file - if it's one of the `config` files (such as `database.yml`), the issue is your `Unlimited` constant won't have been initialized yet.

--

If you provide more context (where you're calling the file & how you need it to work), it will give us a much better understanding of how to make it work